# Calculate X position where string ends

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a string with some font size & added that text on UIView using drawInRect method. I am able to calculate the approx Y position of the string by calculating its height, but I want to know the X position as well.

Can I calculate the x location of string where my string gets end.

string length & font size can vary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps calling [`CGContextGetTextPosition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17031) after drawing the string will give you the coordinate you need.

For more information, read [the “Text” chapter of *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH213-TPXREF101).

Comment: Got Solved. Thanks rob mayoff :)